# Error 404 when assigning a hostname in binding a site in IIS 10

Tags: iis, hostname

I have two websites under IIS (same IP). I want to map them to

```
website 1: domainname.com (80)
website 1 ssl: https://domainname.com (443)
website 2: sub.domainname.com (80)
```

problem is, when I add hostname to the binding, I get error 404 when I browse the site. site works fine when I remove the hostname in the binding.

help?

Comment: Run Jexus Manager Binding Diagnostics to learn the bindings.